# PS user creation script (

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm making PS script which is going to make users from arrays. Everything works fine with this on:

```
New-ADUser `
-Name $naam  `
-SamAccountName $naam -UserPrincipalName $usprinc `
-AccountPassword $password `
-HomeDrive X: `
-HomeDirectory $eigenmap `
-Path "$lastou, OU=USERS_ABC, OU= BEDRIJF ABC, DC= kurzynowski, DC= local" `
-PassThru | Enable-ADAccount
```

When I'm making users this way, their home dirs aren't created. I've checked AD users and computers for each user properties. Each user has correct path and drive letter in their home dir. But i get no dirs for those users in my share. Anybody has idea y?

Comment: Have you tried to sign into computers with these accounts? I wonder if they are not created automatically since you are not using AD to populate the fields.

Comment: afaik the new-aduser cmdlet does not create the home drive for you when creating a new user.  I suspect that the folders will be generated at the users first login but you may be better off creating them manually with new-item, which would also give you more control over the permissions.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/04/creating-a-home-drive-with-windows-powershell-part-1/ has some more info you may find helpful.

Comment: I usually recommend creating home directories with a logon script (e.g. `if not exist \\server\homes\%username% md \\server\homes\%username%`).

Comment: HomeFolder-creation is a function in the GUI, not in the AD itself, so you would have to create (and set ACLs) manually with your own PowerShell-code.

Comment: Creating the folder with a logon script automatically takes care of the ACLs, provided permissions on the home share were set [correctly](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/30/automatic-creation-of-user-folders-for-home-roaming-profile-and-redirected-folders/).

Comment: So what is -HomeDirectory for? It appears in properties like one gui added but it doesn't work (only way to fix it is by clicking profile path and then back on home folder to reaply). I just wanted one creation script to do the job, nothing fancy. And now my only choices are to install GUI or to apply logon scripts. Setting GPO would be to easy :)

Comment: The parameter exists so you can configure the home directory on the account object. If you want one script to rule them a^W^W^Wcreate both account and home directory you need to create the folder in the script as well (e.g. via `New-Item`) and also adjust its permissions.

Comment: But it should inherit from the folder above which already exists. So only thing I need is folder, which cmdled should I use to create this folder?